# Need javolution and jdk version

Tags: java

I want to know the javolution and jna jar version which is supported by jdk 1.4.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Both Javolution and JNA are documented to work with 1.4. If you run into any concrete problems, please ask about *those*. Also: asking to reply ASAP is considered very rude.

Comment: I am so sorry for being rude, but I didn mean it.
I want to know the version of Javolution and JNA which can be supported by JDK 1.4.
I am using Javolution(5.2.6) but it is for J2SE(1.5+).
I want to know the version which is for J2SE(1.4).
Once again I am so sorry.

Comment: @sneha you can edit your question if you want to change your wording.

Answer (score 1):

There is a pre built release for Javolution 5.5.1 which appears to be for Java 5.0.  However, using `ant` it can built for j2me, gcj, 1.4, 1.5 and 1.6.